# Zend_Form not displaying error message with calling addError

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form

I am implementing an updatePasswordAction and its not displaying an error with an invalid current password. I could not implement this with a Zend_Validate class to use with a supplied record->password, so i just validated for now in my controller action and if failed then i add the error message to the form element. this is just before i run `$form->isValid`. In any case, its working. but when the validation fails, its not displaying the error message on this on the element. any help would be greatly appreciated.

FYI: When I submit a blank current password, it shows the validation

```
class Admin_Form_UserPassword extends Katana_Form
{
    public function init()
    {
    $element = $this->createElement('hidden', 'id');
    $this->addElement($element);

    $element = $this->createElement('password','password');
    $element->setLabel('Current Password:');
    $element->setRequired(true);        
    $this->addElement($element);

    $element = $this->createElement('password','new_password');     
    $element->setLabel('New Password:');
    $element->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(6,24));     
    $element->setRequired(true);
    $element->addValidator('NotEmpty');     
    $this->addElement($element);

    $element = $this->createElement('password','new_password_confirm');
    $element->setLabel('Confirm:');
    $element->addValidator('StringLength', false, array(6,24));
    $element->addValidator('IdenticalField', false, array('new_password', 'Confirm Password'));
    $element->setRequired(true);
    $this->addElement($element);

    $this->addElement('submit', 'submit', array('label' => 'Submit'));
}
```

}

```
public function updatePasswordAction()
{
    $resourceModel  = new Core_Model_Resource_User();       
    $form           = new Admin_Form_UserPassword();
    $form->setMethod(Katana_Form::METHOD_POST);
    $form->setAction($this->getActionUrl('update-password'));
    if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        $id             = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $record         = $resourceModel->find($id)->current();
        $currPassword   = $record->password;
        $typedPassword  = md5($this->getRequest()->getParam('password'));           
        if($currPassword !== $typedPassword){               
            $form->getElement('password')->addError('Current password is incorrect.');
        }
        if($form->isValid($_POST)){
            $data       = $form->getValues();
            $result     = $resourceModel->updatePassword($id, $data['new_password']);
            if($result){
                $this->redirectSimple('list');
            }
        }
    } else {
        $id     = $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');          
        $recordData = array(
            'id' => $id
        );
        $form->populate($recordData);           
    }
    $this->getView()->form = $form;     
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by 'not working'? Are there some errors? Nothing happens? etc..

Comment: When I submit an invalid currentpassword, its not displaying the error message. it should, as within the updatePasswordAction, i use $form->getElement('password')->addError('Current password is incorrect.') just before i run if($form->isValid($_POST)){

Comment: `Zend_Form_Element::addError()` is additional function and you must use `Zend_Form::getErrorMessages()` to retrieve them. Do you use `getErrorMessagess()`?

Comment: Shouldnt me setting the error before isValid cause the form to be invalidated and automatically set the error message for the current password element. It does this when the element is blank, so it should do it when the currentpassword is incorrect.

Comment: Do you get the mesage `Current password is incorrect` when element is blank?

Comment: Yes. But not when the current password doesnt equal the record password

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/6975/discussion-between-bartekr-and-jonathan-kushner)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding an error to the element doesn't cause the form itself to then be invalid.

There are at least 2 methods I use to get around this:

```
if($currPassword !== $typedPassword){               
    $form->getElement('password')->addError('Current password is incorrect.');
    $form->markAsError();
}

// or

if ($form->isValid($_POST) && 0 == sizeof($form->getMessages()) {
    // form was valid, and no errors were set on elements
}
```

To clarify, when you add the error to the form ELEMENT, there is an error attached to that element, but Zend_Form::isValid only runs the validators and sets appropriate errors, it doesn't check to see if you had set an error on a particular element.

You can however call `$form->getMessages()` to get all the error messages attached to the form or its child elements.  If this is 0 and you have validated your form, then it means there were no errors.  If your form passed `isValid` but you added an error to an element, it will include the error message you added.

Answer (score 0):

I made it work this way.

Controller:

```
if ($trial->getKind() != 'debt' && $_POST['kind'] == 'debt')
{
    $editForm->getElement('kind')->markAsError();
}

if ($editForm->isValid($_POST)) { ... }
```

Form:

```
public function isValid($data)
{
    $valid = parent::isValid($data);

    if ($this->getElement('kind')->hasErrors()) {
        $this->getElement('kind')->addError($this->_translate->translate('You can\'t change trial kind to debt.'));
        $valid = false;
    }

    return $valid;
}
```

And [this comment](http://framework.zend.com/issues/browse/ZF-5150?focusedCommentId=36445#comment-36445) helped me.